# google cloud vision API error "Deadline expired before operation could complete."

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I got the cloud vision API working, and I was having lots of fun tagging my images. I've only tested it on about 50 images. It was working yesterday. When I tried again today, I got an error. For the label annotation, the error is:

**"Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check** quota)."

For face detection, the error is:

**"Deadline expired before operation could complete."**

I don't think I have gone over the 1,000 monthly limit, but I can't figure out how to check. Does anyone know?

Or, does anyone have any ideas about why this would have happened if I am indeed below the 1,000 request limit (which I am pretty sure I am!)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I've been getting the same error responses. I think it's a server-side error, rather than actual quota limits being reached.

Comment: Ditto to @DaveStarling.

Comment: FYI, it seems to be back up and running now. It's beta, so you shouldn't expect (but maybe hope for) 100% reliability.

Comment: Thanks guys! It's working well now.

Comment: Is there a way to mark this as 'resolved'?

Comment: Just put in some answer, and mark it as such. For service problems check https://status.firebase.google.com/

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, you can check your quote using the API Manager in the [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com).

On the left-nav, jump to API Manager Dashboard, then search for the Vision API.

The Vision API dashboard will have a "Quotas" tab that shows you how many requests have been made, etc.

You can also look at the Quotas page in the IAM & Admin section of the console, and filter by Service ("Google Cloud Vision API"):

[image: Quote demo]